# Angular5 Custom validators : ng: Identified 'passwordG' is not definded.

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

Working in angular5 trying to implement custom validators for password and confirmation password .

*This is .html  :*

```
 <div formGroupName = "passwordG">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vat">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat"    formControlName="password" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vat">Confirmation Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat" formControlName="Confirmationpassword" />
    </div>


    <div *ngIf="(passwordG.invalid && passwordG.touched)" class="col-sm-3 text-danger">

      <ng-container *ngIf="passwordG.errors?.mismatch;
            then first else second"> </ng-container>

      <ng-template #first>
        Password do not match </ng-template>

      <ng-template #second>
        Password needs to be more than 8 characters
      </ng-template>
    </div>

    </div>
```

*In .ts :*

```
ngOnInit() {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

  passwordG: this.formBuilder.group({
    password: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
    Confirmationpassword : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]]

  }, {validator: passwordMatch})

});
}
```

*In the same file .ts , out this class i have a function :*

```
 function passwordMatch(control: AbstractControl):{[key: string]: boolean}{

  const password = control.get('password');
  const Confirmationpassword = control.get('Confirmationpassword');

  if( !password || !Confirmationpassword) {
    return null; }

  if(password.value === Confirmationpassword.value){
    return null;
  }

  return {
    mismatch:true
  }

}
```

The problem is in .html file i get this error :

```
ng: Identified 'passwordG' is not definded. The component declaration ,Template variable declaration and element reference do not contain such a member  ,
```

At line  :

```
<div *ngIf="(passwordG.invalid && passwordG.touched)" class="col-sm-3 text-danger">
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Use `form.controls['passwordG']` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) , if you can add it as answer so i can mark it for you :)

Comment: No problem @dEs12ZER :) Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passwordG` itself is not defined in the component.

If you want to access a control in the form, you can use

`form.controls['passwordG']` or `form.get('passwordG')`